# ostream default parameter in template function

Tags: c++, templates, io

In the book "Essential C++" (more specifically, part 2.7), the author briefly discusses the usage of template functions with the following example, which displays a diagnostic message and then iterates through the elements of a vector

```
template <typename T> 
void display_message(const string& msg, const vector<T>& vec)
{
    cout << msg; 

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        cout << vec[i] << ' '; 
}
```

So, this example got me interested, because i (as many other hobbyist developers, probably) have always taken for granted that in most applications, the standard input/output streams are being used for communication and data processing. The author then mentions that this way of implementing display_message is more flexible. Can you give me an example of a situation where this flexability "shines", so to speak? In other words, is there a case where the optional 3rd parameter takes on another input/output representation (say, an embedded device) or it is just a simple addition that is supposed to be used with, well, simple constructions instead of the extreme situations i am trying to describe?

EDIT: As **@Matteo Italia** noticed, this is the function declaration

```
void display_message(const string&, const vector<T>&, ostream& = cout);
```

Comment: That third argument makes no sense (although it compiles), are you sure it's written that way? Isn't it more like `ostream &os = cout`, and in the rest of the function body it uses `os` instead of `cout`?

Comment: Ah, yes! My bad. I've presented the function declaration. You're right, of course.

Comment: Uhm, now the definition is off... you are missing the third parameter.

Comment: Ahh, this is what happens when you hurry to edit an edit! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing two "flexibilities" available in this function.

- the *template* part (which I think is the one the author is talking about) allows you to pass any `std::vector<T>` given that `T` can be output on the stream; i.e. you can pass a vector of integers, doubles, or even of your custom objects and the function will happily output it on the given stream;<sup>1</sup>
- the *stream* part (which caught your attention) is instead to allow you to specify any (narrow) output stream for the output part; it's useful because you may want to output your message (and your vector) on some other streams; for example, if it's an error message you'll want `cerr`; and, most importantly, if you are writing to file, you'll pass your file stream.

---

*Notes*

1. notice that in more "STL<sup>2</sup>-like" interfaces typically you won't receive a vector like that, but more probably a couple of iterators. Actually, the standard library prefers an even more abstract way to solve this problem (`std::ostream_iterator`, which allow you to use `std::copy` to copy data from container iterators to the output stream);
2. to nitpickers: I know and you won't convince me.

Comment: @TheSOFan: glad it helped; in this case on StackOverflow it's customary to *accept* the answer (click the tick near the votes count); if you didn't know this, you should do that with your older questions as well (it gives some points also to you).